# React/Firebase. How can i filter some products by categories using firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, filter

How can i filter some products by categories using firebase? [This is a fragment of my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-flower-nqq6cr)

Comment: Please, clarify your question, what you tried, what you expect, what your data looks like, where exactly you want to filter, in the UI in Map function, in the State variable, or you want to query them from database with firestore query api. Also, if you are using Firebase Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: @SergeySosunov I'm sorry for a long answer! I've added database in link above. I'm using a firebase firestore and I would like to filter it through the map function. when I clicking on a category, I would like to display products according to the category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have a correct db.json file, i had to flatMap the result but here is a working code. I used require to load you json file and left `const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);` just in case. Also i switched `categories` to `useMemo` so this variable will not update on each re-render.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const dbProducs = require("./db.json");

const CategoriesPage = () => {
  // const {product} = useContext(Context)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const categories = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      { id: 1, title: "Tablets" },
      { id: 2, title: "Computers" },
      { id: 3, title: "Consoles" },
      { id: 4, title: "Photo and video" },
      { id: 5, title: "Technics" },
      { id: 6, title: "Game Content" },
      { id: 7, title: "Notebooks" },
      { id: 8, title: "Smartphones" },
      { id: 9, title: "Headphones" },
      { id: 10, title: "Steam" }
      // {id: 11,imageSrc:steamcards, title: 'Стиральные машины'},
      // {id: 12,imageSrc: coffeemaschine, title: 'One stars'},
      // {id: 13,imageSrc:headphones, title: 'Холодильники'},
    ];
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const flatMapped = dbProducs.flatMap((x) => x.products);
    setProducts(flatMapped);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="popular__categories">
      <h3 className="events__title">
        <span>Categories</span>
      </h3>
      <div className="categories__wrapper">
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <Link
            to={`${category.id}`}
            className="categories__content"
            key={category.id}
          >
            <h2 className="categories__title">{category.title}</h2>
            <img
              className="categories__img"
              alt={category.title}
              src={category.imageSrc}
            />
            <ul>
              {products
                .filter((p) => p.category === category.title)
                .map((p) => (
                  <li key={p.id}>{p.name}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default CategoriesPage;
```

Technically it would be better to clone and extend your `categories` objects with additional array property with useMemo, or you can add additional Map object with key = Category(title) and value = products (filtered) but it is up to you.

Full example with Context, Routes, Navigation:

[image: Edit React Context example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, it works, but it's not exactly what I need. When I am clicking on a category I need to go to a separate page, where these products will be displayed sorted by category. Don't you know how to do it?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it... I'm trying to use a hook `useParams`, but its working for a category database, not for a products database. I will be very grateful if you help me

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! [I have updated the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-flower-nqq6cr). I added CategoriesPage (with categories) and CategoriesDetailsPage ( where products should be placed). I hope this information would be enough. If something is missing or you have any questions - please ask! I will try my best to answer them and help you too!

Comment: God thank you! You're my life saver! This is what i needed! Thank you so much!! About the back arrow. I think this is how codesandbox works under the hood